# Onvif c# event subscription

Tags: c#, onvif

I would like to get events from the ip camera my steps are:

send a subscripbe request using a NotificationProducerClient:

```
        using (var client = new NotificationProducerClient(Bind, new EndpointAddress(EventsServiceAddress)))
        {
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "un";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pw";

            var subScribe = new Subscribe() {
                ConsumerReference = new EndpointReferenceType1 {
                    Address = new AttributedURIType { Value = "My service URL" },
                },
                InitialTerminationTime = "PT1M"
            };
            subRes = client.Subscribe(subScribe);

        }
```

but after subscription I cant get any notification in my Service runnig instance.

1. Have I done something wrong?
2. what is the subscription reference in the subscribe Response, Anything to do with it?

I see there are some question on this topic here, but no one answered
Hope to get an answer...

Thanks